# Word gives error when iSCSI is detached

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a drive D: connected via iSCSI to a NAS with RAID. The drive is not used for anything critical such as page file, user profiles, temp dir or anything similar.

Every now and then the connection to this iSCSI device is broken, for example due to network failure or upgrading NAS. And every time, if open with document, Word 2016 gives me an error.

"Word had trouble reading from your file."
[image: Error from Word]

It doesn't matter if document is opened from C: or if its a blank document I haven't saved yet. When D: is disconnected the error pops up. Clicking Retry-button brings back same error (endless loop).

Cancel gives me a new error:
[image: Second error]

And clicking OK tells me that Word has lost data due to bad network connection:
[image: Third error]

After that Word closes and recent changes are lost.

It doesn't help to bring back iSCSI D: and click "Retry" at the first error message. The error message persists until Word is restarted.

It would seem that for some reason Word puts a temp file on my D:. Why does it do this? How do I stop it?

Word should not touch my slow networked drive D:, it should work on my fast SSD RAID which is C:. I've checked options, and under "Save" all paths point to C:. And no add-ins run from d:.

Comment: Give this a try to start and see if it helps in case it does resolve and it's simple enough for you. Ensure the "D", NAS, etc. is up and mounted and then uninstall MS Office Word / MS Office, reboot the machine. Dismount the "D" drive or NAS, etc. and only have the OS core C boot drive available and then reinstall MS Word / MS Office. With keeping "D" dismounted test and then reboot, and then test Word with the "D" mounted then dismount with Word open, etc. I'm just suggesting this as this would be something I'd try and feel comfortable doing. Check Event Viewer Logs for errors too first tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and found that Word uses IE's "Temporary Internet Files" folder for temporary storage. IE Temp folder is pointed to D:\System\IECache (by me). I really could not imagine this would affect Office, but apparently so.

```
D:\System\IECache\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Word\~WRS{693BB2D9-F03C-41B8-BFC8-56B776636C8D}.tmp
```